# Weakly convergent subsequence

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Is it true that any bounded sequence of a (separable) Hilbert space contains a weakly convergent subsequence?
I would say yes because, by Banach-Alaoglu theorem I can say that any bounded sequence contains a subsequence weakly* convergent, and since an Hilbert space is reflexive by Milman-Pettis theorem, the weak* convergence implies weak convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is incomplete. Compact topological spaces need not be sequentially compact. So Banach Alaoglu  Theorem only gives you a convergent **subnet**, not necessarily a convergent subsequence.

The answer is YES. By Banach Alaoglu Theorem the closed unit ball of $H$ is weakly compact. By separability this implies that the ball is also metrizable. Hence, the closed unit ball is a compact metric space in weak topology and any sequence has a convergent subsequence. Same is true of close ball of any radius.

[The closed unit ball of $X^{*}$ is  a compact metric space in the weak* topology whenever $X$ is separable Banach space].

Comment: Is also my solution correct or not?

Comment: @hobal51825 I have edited my answer.

Comment: In my notes I found this proposition:

If X is separable and reflexive then any bounded sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset X$ has a weakly convergent subsequence in $X$.

Can I say that: Hilbert space is reflexive (for the same reason explained in the main question) and separable by hypothesis, then for the proposition any bounded seq contains a weakly convergent subseq.? (Banach Alaoglu theorem is used in the proof of the proposition)

Comment: Yes, that is correct but you should have quoted that result explcitly in the proof. Separability is essential for this result and yo had to say exactly how it is used in the proof. @hobal51825

Comment: Since $X$ is separable and reflexive, then $X^*$ (dual) is separable and I can apply Banach Alaoglu theorem to a sequence $\{\tau(x_n)\}_{n \subset \mathbb N} \subset X^{**}$ (bidual) finding $\tau(x_{n_h})$ weak* convergent to $\Lambda$. Finally, since X is reflexive I have that $x=\tau^{-1}(\Lambda)$ and $x_{n_h}$ weakly converges to $x$

Comment: In the last sentence, when I say that "since X is reflexive I have that $x=\tau^{-1}(\Lambda)$ and $x_{n_h}$ weakly converges to $x$", the correct procedure is that "since X is reflexive I have that $x=\tau^{-1}(\Lambda)$ so $x_{n_h}$ weakly* converges to $x$ but since $X$ is reflexive, the weak* convergence implies the weak convergence so $x_{n_h}$ weakly converges to $x$"?.